# What is the subject of a cynic called?

Tags: word-choice

According to the dictionary, a **cynic** is:

> a person who believes that only selfishness motivates human actions and who disbelieves in or minimizes selfless acts or disinterested points of view.

Alice is a cynic. She uses Bob as an example to illustrate her point of view. What's the best term (preferably a single word) she can use to describe Bob?

You could say that Bob is ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**.

For example, given the definition above, you could say that Bob is selfish. However, I believe that this doesn't sum up all of the things Alice believes about him...

Comment: Based on your comments, perhaps a better way to describe the question would be: "Alice is a cynic. She uses Bob as an example to illustrate her point of view. What word would she use to describe Bob?"

Comment: Answer: "Reality."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the definition of *cynic*, some words to describe Bob would be:

[**selfish**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/selfish)

> 1. Holding one’s self-interest as the standard for decision making
> 2. Having regard for oneself above others’ well-being

[**greedy**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greedy)

> 1. Having [greed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greed) (a selfish or excessive desire for more than is needed or deserved, especially of money, wealth, food, or other possessions); consumed by selfish desires

[**egotistical**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egotistical)

> 1. Believing oneself to be better and more important than others

If you are looking for a single word to describe all possibilities, I think **selfish** is the best choice. *Egotistical* implies thinking highly of oneself, but this does not necessarily translate into selfish behavior. *Greedy* is also a good choice, but tends to relate specifically to material possessions.

***Update:*** If you are flexible on the single-word requirement, a suitable phrase would be:

[**self-serving**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/self-serving)

> 1. Serving one's own interests, especially without concern for the needs or interests of others
> 2. Exhibiting concern solely for one's own interests: a speech full of self-serving comments

Comment: I think the situation that the OP is describing that Bob is not himself cynical, but that Alice believes that Bob's actions are motivated by selfishness.

Comment: Alice is the cynical one, not Bob. He behaves that way, but doesn't necessarily believe that others do.

Comment: @waiwai933: The OP states that Alice "is correct" in her assessment of Bob. I understood that to mean that he *is* cynical.

Comment: @Senseful: OK, I think I understand now. Let me think on it.

Comment: Sorry it's confusing, @e.James, but @waiwai933 is right

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for... a term that describes those three words (possibly more?) all at once.

Comment: How about *self-serving*? It's not really one word, but I think it conveys the correct meaning.

Answer (score 2):

A cynic is a person that believes these attributes to be true for humanity, not for a single person or group. If she - Alice - would only believe it to be true for Bob, then she would not be a cynic.

If Alice believes that selfishness motivates Bob, Bob would be an egoist or plain selfish.

If Alice believes, and is correct with her believe, that Bob believes  that only selfishness motivates human actions and disbelieves in or minimizes selfless acts or disinterested points of view, then Bob would be a cynic no matter whether Alice was one or not.

Comment: @Ralph, sorry the wording was confusing. I updated the question to hopefully be clearer.